# Sorting rows in SQL based on an integer key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have a pretty simple table that looks like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| CategoryId | CategoryName             | SubCategoryId |
|------------|--------------------------|---------------|
| 32         | Sports Bar               | 30            |
| 29         | Automotive Services      | 0             |
| 120        | Dance Studio             | 116           |
| 116        | Arts and Hobbies         | 0             |
| 24         | Telecommunications       | 0             |
| 40         | Body Shop                | 29            |
| 41         | Tires                    | 29            |
| 30         | Restaurant/Tavern        | 0             |
| 60         | Coffee House             | 30            |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

The `SubCategoryId` determines what category that category should fall under. If its `0`, then that means its a top level category. For example, `Tires` would fall under the category whose category id is `29`, which is `Automotive Services`.

My question is, how can I sort this so that the top level category comes first, followed by the subcategories under that category. For example, in the table above, I wanted it sorted like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| CategoryId | CategoryName             | SubCategoryId |
|------------|--------------------------|---------------|
| 116        | Arts and Hobbies         | 0             |
| 120        | Dance Studio             | 116           |
| 29         | Automotive Services      | 0             |
| 40         | Body Shop                | 29            |
| 41         | Tires                    | 29            |
| 30         | Restaurant/Tavern        | 0             |
| 60         | Coffee House             | 30            |
| 32         | Sports Bar               | 30            |
| 24         | Telecommunications       | 0             |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried the following query, but its getting an error:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Category CAT 
ORDER BY (SELECT CategoryId FROM Category CAT2 WHERE CAT.CategoryId=CAT2.SubCategoryId), CategoryName
```

Comment: Do you have multiple levels of subcategory? Ie under Body Shop, can there be Paint Shop and Panel Shop; then under Paint Shop there  can be others...OR is it strictly a 2 level situation?

Comment: @simo.379209 - It is strictly a 2 level situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with cats as
 (select categoryname,
         categoryid,
         row_number() over(order by categoryname) as cat_rn
    from tbl
   where subcategoryid = 0)
select x.*
  from (select case
                 when c.cat_rn is null
                 then c2.categoryid
                 else t.categoryid
                  end as par,
               t.categoryid,
               t.categoryname,
               t.subcategoryid
          from tbl t
          left join cats c
            on t.categoryid = c.categoryid
          left join cats c2
            on t.subcategoryid = c2.categoryid) x
  join cats c
    on x.par = c.categoryid
 order by c.cat_rn,
          case when x.subcategoryid = 0 then '0' else x.categoryname end
```

**Fiddle:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/548781/13/0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT cat.*
FROM dbo.Category CAT LEFT JOIN
     dbo.Category subcat
     ON cat.SubCateogryId = subcat.CategoryId
ORDER BY subcat.CategoryId,
          (case when subcat.CategoryId is null then 1 else 0 end) desc,
         CategoryName;
```

It joins in the subcategory information, but only uses it for the sort.